# Преобразование вершин в полосу треугольников\квадратов

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, геометрия

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой при попытке написать загрузчик OBJ файлов для отображения их в OpenGL (под врапером Tao Framework на C#). Мне удалось наладить загрузку координат вершин и текстур, однако координаты вершин не подходят для отображения моделей - насколько я знаю, в OpenGL не существует такого метода отрисовки. Собственно вопрос: как преобразовать координаты в вершин в координаты полосы треугольников\квадратов\отдельных треугольников\квадратов? Полигон был бы нежелателен.
Вот собственно, сам загрузчик:

```
public static Mesh MeshFromFile(string filename)
            {
                if (filename.EndsWith(".obj"))
                {
                    string rawfile = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                    string file = rawfile;
                    string[] rawcoords;
                    float[] coords;
                    float[] texcoords;

                    file = file.Remove(0, file.IndexOf(Resourses.OBJ_coords_beginning) + 5);
                    file = file.Remove(file.IndexOf("#"));
                    file = file.Replace("v  ", " ");
                    file = file.Replace('.', ',');
                    rawcoords = file.Split(' ');

                    coords = new float[rawcoords.Length];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string s in rawcoords)
                    {
                        coords[i] = Convert.ToSingle(s);
                        i++;
                    }

                    file = rawfile;
                    file = file.Remove(0, file.IndexOf(Resourses.OBJ_texcoords_beginning) + 14);
                    file = file.Remove(file.IndexOf("#") - 1);
                    file = file.Replace("vt  ", " ");
                    file = file.Replace('.', ',');
                    rawcoords = file.Split(' ');

                    texcoords = new float[rawcoords.Length - (rawcoords.Length / 3)];
                    i = 0;
                    int skip = 0;
                    foreach (string s in rawcoords)
                    {
                        if (skip != 2)
                        {
                            texcoords[i] = Convert.ToSingle(s);
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            skip = -1;
                        }
                        skip++;
                    }

                    return new Mesh(coords, texcoords, Mesh.Type.Quad_strip);
                }
                return null;
            }
```

*Примечание:* Mesh - это собственноручный написанный мною класс для отображаемых моделей. В данном коде я задаю координаты вершин, координаты текстур и метод отрисовки (из моего перечисления, которое базируется на константах OpenGL) через конструктор этого класса, и затем возвращаю экземпляр для последующей отрисовки.

Вот образец куба:

```
    # Max2Obj Version 4.0 Mar 10th, 2001
#
# object Pretty_cube0 to come ...
#
v  -20.000000 0.000000 20.000000
v  20.000000 0.000000 20.000000
v  -20.000000 0.000000 -20.000000
v  20.000000 0.000000 -20.000000
v  -20.000000 40.000000 20.000000
v  20.000000 40.000000 20.000000
v  -20.000000 40.000000 -20.000000
v  20.000000 40.000000 -20.000000
# 8 vertices

vt  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vt  0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt  1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
# 12 texture vertices

vn  0.000000 -2.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 -2.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 2.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn  0.000000 2.000000 -0.000000
# 8 vertex normals

g Pretty_cube0
s 2
f 1/10/1 3/12/3 4/11/4
f 4/11/4 2/9/2 1/10/1
s 4
f 5/9/5 6/10/6 8/12/8
f 8/12/8 7/11/7 5/9/5
s 8
f 1/5/1 2/6/2 6/8/6
f 6/8/6 5/7/5 1/5/1
s 16
f 2/1/2 4/2/4 8/4/8
f 8/4/8 6/3/6 2/1/2
s 32
f 4/5/4 3/6/3 7/8/7
f 7/8/7 8/7/8 4/5/4
s 64
f 3/1/3 1/2/1 5/4/5
f 5/4/5 7/3/7 3/1/3
# 12 faces

g
```

Сферу не стал помещать из-за большого числа вершин.
А вот самые лучшие результаты (QUAD_STRIP):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, данные о сторонах модели указаны в самом файле. После долгой возни с ними я наконец-то создал нормально работающий загрузчик. Правда, в нём требует доработки отображение модели при сторонах, указанных не в треугольниках, а в четырёхугольниках - на данный момент я изменил только способ отображения, однако я недосчитываюсь некоторых вершин, когда рассматриваю конечный результат.
Предоставляю код загрузчика всем желающим *(разумеется, вам придётся его дорабатывать - по крайней мере, избавиться от моего конструктора экземпляра Mesh или вообще возвращать лишь нужные координаты)*:

```
public static Mesh MeshFromFile(string filename)
            {
                if (filename.EndsWith(".obj"))
                {
                    string rawfile = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                    string file = rawfile;
                    string[] rawcoords;
                    string[] tmpcoords;
                    float[] coords;
                    float[] texcoords;
                    int[] faces;

                    //Получаем координаты вершин
                    file = file.Remove(0, file.IndexOf(Resourses.OBJ_coords_beginning) + 5);
                    file = file.Remove(file.IndexOf("#"));
                    file = file.Replace("v  ", " ");
                    file = file.Replace('.', ',');
                    rawcoords = file.Split(' ');

                    coords = new float[rawcoords.Length];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string s in rawcoords)
                    {
                        coords[i] = Convert.ToSingle(s);
                        i++;
                    }

                    //Получаем координаты текстур
                    file = rawfile;
                    file = file.Remove(0, file.IndexOf(Resourses.OBJ_texcoords_beginning) + 14);
                    file = file.Remove(file.IndexOf("#") - 1);
                    file = file.Replace("vt  ", " ");
                    file = file.Replace('.', ',');
                    rawcoords = file.Split(' ');

                    texcoords = new float[rawcoords.Length];
                    i = 0;
                    foreach (string s in rawcoords)
                    {
                            texcoords[i] = Convert.ToSingle(s);
                            i++;
                    }

                    //Faces
                    file = rawfile;
                    file = file.Remove(0, file.IndexOf("f") + 1);
                    file = file.Remove(file.IndexOf("#") - 1);
                    tmpcoords = file.Split(' ');

                    int b = 0;
                    rawcoords = new string[tmpcoords.Length * 3];
                    foreach(string s in tmpcoords)
                    {
                        if (s.Split('/').Length == 3)
                        {
                            rawcoords[b] = s.Split('/')[0];
                            rawcoords[b + 1] = s.Split('/')[1];
                            rawcoords[b + 2] = s.Split('/')[2];
                            b += 3;

                        }
                    }
                    Array.Resize(ref rawcoords, b);


                    for (int x = 0; x < rawcoords.Length; x++)
                    {
                        if (rawcoords[x].Contains("s"))
                        {
                            rawcoords[x] = rawcoords[x].Remove(rawcoords[x].Length - 2);
                        }
                        if (rawcoords[x].Contains("f"))
                        {
                            rawcoords[x] = rawcoords[x].Remove(rawcoords[x].Length - 2);
                        }
                    }

                    faces = new int[rawcoords.Length];
                    i = 0;
                    foreach (string s in rawcoords)
                    {
                        if (s.EndsWith("0") | s.EndsWith("1") | s.EndsWith("2") | s.EndsWith("3") | s.EndsWith("4") | s.EndsWith("5") | s.EndsWith("6") | s.EndsWith("7") | s.EndsWith("8") | s.EndsWith("9"))
                        {
                            faces[i] = Convert.ToInt32(s);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    Array.Resize(ref faces, i);
                    //Получаем координаты точек и текстуры, исходя с данных сторон
                    float[] fin_coords = new float[faces.Length];
                    float[] fin_texcoords = new float[faces.Length];


                    int d = 0;
                    int t = 0;
                    //Получаем режим для отрисовки (5 - GL_TRIANGLES, 3 - GL_QUADS)
                    if (faces.Length / coords.Length == 5)
                    for (int c = 0; c < faces.Length; c += 3)
                    {
                        fin_coords[d] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3];                 
                        fin_coords[d + 1] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3 + 1];
                        fin_coords[d + 2] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3 + 2];

                        fin_texcoords[t] = texcoords[(faces[c + 1] - 1) * 3];
                        fin_texcoords[t + 1] = texcoords[(faces[c + 1] - 1) * 3 + 1];

                        d += 3;
                        t += 2;
                    }
                    else
                        if(faces.Length / coords.Length == 3)
                        for (int c = 0; c < faces.Length; c += 3)
                        {
                            fin_coords[d] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3];
                            fin_coords[d + 1] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3 + 1];
                            fin_coords[d + 2] = coords[(faces[c] - 1) * 3 + 2];

                            fin_texcoords[t] = texcoords[(faces[c + 1] - 1) * 3];
                            fin_texcoords[t + 1] = texcoords[(faces[c + 1] - 1) * 3 + 1];

                            d += 3;
                            t += 2;
                        }


                    Array.Resize(ref fin_coords, d);
                    Array.Resize(ref fin_texcoords, d);

                    return new Mesh(fin_coords, fin_texcoords, faces.Length / coords.Length == 5 ? Mesh.Type.Triangles : Mesh.Type.Quads);
                }
                return null;
            }
```